# Facebook API 2.8: Getting Members of a FriendList object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to list all friends who use my app and belong to a FriendList object.  The FriendList object could be, for example, 'Close Friends', or 'Family'.  I understand that I can get a full list of friends who use my App using the `/me/friends` endpoint, but that's not what I am looking for.  I need only those who belong to a given FriendList.

When I `GET /{{friend-list-id}}/?metadata=1` the metadata shows a 'connections' object with a 'members' property.  The value of the members property is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{friend-list-id}}/members
```

When I hit this URL (and include my access token), I get a `FacebookResponseException` with the message '(#12) Unavailable in this version'.  I am using API v2.8.

Is it really the case that I can't get the contents of the FriendList?  (Remember that I am only needing those that use my app).

Alternatively, is there a way that I can filter the `/me/friends` response so that it includes only those who are on a given FriendList?

Comment: You are correct. You can not get people in a friend list.